# Add character to string in SQL

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, char

I have got two strings:

```
12, H220, H280
```

and

```
11, 36, 66, 67, H225, H319, H336
```

and I want to add character A to every place where there is no 'H', so the strings should look like

```
A12, H220, H280
```

and

```
A11, A36, A66, A67, H225, H319, H336
```

Comment: Why do you store comma separated strings instead of a single record for every token?

Comment: I have got it like that.

Comment: @user3690217 this could suggest a bad design,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

```
select REPLACE(Test,Test,'A'+Test) from   (
select REPLACE(Test,', ', ',A') Test from (
select REPLACE(Test,', H',',H') Test from (
select '11, 36, 66, 67, H225, H319, H336' as Test) S) S1 ) S2
```

Comment: Put the long string into a variable and use it instead of the string literal '11, 36, 66, 67, H225, H319, H336'.

Comment: If it works out then it would be the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/37041)**

```
--Sample data
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, COL1 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT @T (ID, COL1)
VALUES (1, '12, H220, H280'), (2, '11, 36, 66, 67, H225, H319, H336')

--Query 
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,  STUFF(COL1, PATINDEX('%[^H]%', COL1), 0, 'A') COL1, 1 NUMBER
    FROM @T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE.ID, STUFF(CTE.COL1, PATINDEX('%[,][ ][^HA]%', CTE.COL1) + 2, 0, 'A'), NUMBER + 1 
    FROM CTE JOIN @T T
        ON CTE.ID = T.ID
    WHERE PATINDEX('%[,][ ][^HA]%', CTE.COL1) > 0
)
,
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NUMBER DESC) rn
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT ID,COL1 FROM CTE2 WHERE RN = 1
```

Results:

```
| ID |                                 COL1 |
|----|--------------------------------------|
|  1 |                      A12, H220, H280 |
|  2 | A11, A36, A66, A67, H225, H319, H336 |
```